# Double integration over $y=x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, multiple-integral

Let us consider arbitrary, integrable, real function $f$.

The point was my trial to slve the following integral

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(z,w)dzdw.$$ I expressed is as the sum

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(z,w)dzdw=\iint\limits_{-\infty<z=w<\infty} f(z,w) dz dw+\iint\limits_{-\infty<z\neq w<\infty} f(z,w) dz dw.$$

To solve the first integral in the previous equation, I employ

$$\iint\limits_{-\infty<z=w<\infty} f(z,w) dz dw= \int_{R} f(z,z) dz.$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The straight line has a Lebesgue measure zero. Then the Lebesgue integral over it is zero. The same with Riemann integral - Riemann integrable functions are Lebesgue integrable and both integrals are equal.

Comment: So, you said that equality I wrote holds or it is equal to 0?

Comment: @Boyan: I'm not sure I would conclude that.  It's not clear to me what your LHS means.  The right-hand integral is pretty clear: It's $\int_{z=-\infty}^\infty g(z) \, dz$, where $g(z) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} f(z, z)$.  In general that would be non-zero.  But your LHS is explicitly a double integral, but restricted to a one-dimensional line $z = w$.  On that integral, I'd agree with this answer and say that the LHS is identically zero (barring anything poorly behaved like the Dirac delta function or something).

Comment: @Boyan: It would probably help if we knew where these integrals arose.  It doesn't seem as though the left-hand integral is of much use.

Comment: @BrianTung Right, this answer is wrong

Comment: I have added more details. Is there any idea?